# How to remove double quotes from the numeric series?

Tags: jquery

How to remove double quotes form data and place the numeric series in []? My php version is 5.3.1 so I can't use json_numeric to convert it during json_ecode

```
[{"name":"First","data":"20,43,34,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"},{"name":"Second","data":"34,32,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"},{"name":"Third","data":"22,22,33,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"},{"name":"Fourth","data":"33,21,22,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"},{"name":"Fifth","data":"23,10,28,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"}]
```

to output as

```
[{"name":"First","data":[20,43,34,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"name":"Second","data":[34,32,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"name":"Third","data":[22,22,33,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"name":"Fourth","data":[33,21,22,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]},{"name":"Fifth","data":[23,10,28,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like this

```
var json = [{"name":"First","data":"20,43,34,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"},{"name":"Second","data":"34,32,23,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"},{"name":"Third","data":"22,22,33,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"},{"name":"Fourth","data":"33,21,22,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"},{"name":"Fifth","data":"23,10,28,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0"}]
var new_arr = []
jQuery.each(json,function(k,o){
    var obj = {};
    obj.name = o.name;
    obj.data = create_numeric_arr(o.data.split(','));
    new_arr.push(obj);
})

function create_numeric_arr(myArray){
    for(var i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) { myArray[i] = parseInt(myArray[i], 10); } 
    return myArray;
}
console.log(new_arr);
```

Comment: This will bypass remaining 11 datas and show up only single data

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/9SNHE/2/

```
$.map(a, function(v) {
    v.data = v.data.split(',');
    $.map(v.data, function(v1) {return parseInt(v1, 10);});
    return v;
});
```